# redirect http and non www to https://www and subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect as it is below

- http must be https ://www.domain.com
- https ://domain.com must be https ://www.domain.com
- http ://www.domain.com must be https ://www.domain.com
- http ://subdomain.domain.com must be https ://subdomain.domain.com

Comment: please try something first from your side then ask.

Comment: I have this.but it does not work very well 

# redirect no-www to www only main domain, not with subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(webijs\.hosting)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect http to https all domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

See below rules for htaccess

```
    # 301 --- http://www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com

    RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]

    # 301 --- https://domain.com => https://www.domain.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain.com/? [L,R=301]

    # 301 --- http://subdomain.domain.com => https://subdomain.domain.com

    RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```